# How to convert a number to a UTF8 char?

Tags: utf-8, special-characters, d

How to convert a number to a UTF8 char ?

It must not be a CTFE function because the input parameter is varying during the run-time. I guess there must be a std function for this but I cant find it. Thx.

```
import std.stdio, std.conv;

char utf8_RT(int nbr)
{
    return to!char(nbr);
}
void main(string args[])
{
    assert( utf8_RT(2665) == '\u2665' );
}
```

obviously fails.

Comment: What do you mean by “number”, “convert”, and “UTF8 char”? (UTF-8 is a transfer encoding for Unicode; it defines encodings for characters, not characters themselves.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "UTF8 char".

If you want an UTF-32 character (i.e. `dchar`), you can simply use `dchar(2665)`.

If you want an UTF-8 string (one Unicode character encoded as one or more UTF-8 code units, i.e. bytes), you can use `to!string(dchar(2665))`. Don't forget to `import std.conv`.

Replace `2665` with the name of your `int` variable, naturally.

Comment: To expand slightly, `char` is a UTF-8 code unit but you are trying to get a UTF-8 code point which can (and is in your example) be more than one code unit. You can use a `string` to store this as CyberShadow recommends because a `string` is just an alias for `immutable(char)[]`.

Another option is `std.utf.encode` which accepts a 4 char length static array result parameter.

Comment: Oh! I was missing something in D, until now I was considering `char` as a "top layout" hiding some `ubyte[]`. f..k.

Comment: @user3661500 Well, if you're getting confused by basic stuff like that, I'd suggest that you read this book on D: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html

Comment: To be fair, `char` was a pretty terrible name for a code unit so the confusion is understandable.

Comment: @eco Well, the situation is pretty much identical with C++ in that regard except that in D we assume that it's a UTF-8 code unit, whereas in C++ it's not assumed to be Unicode. But regardless, the misunderstanding is basic enough that I think that it merits studying the basics of the language a lot more thoroughly, since if you don't know even know what `char` really is, who knows what other basic misunderstandings you might have.